# Regex to replace email address domains?

Tags: regex, email, replace

I need a regex to obfuscate emails in a database dump file I have. I'd like to replace all domains with a set domain like `@fake.com` so I don't risk sending out emails to real people during development. The emails do have to be unique to match database constraints, so I only want to replace the domain and keep the usernames.

I current have this regex for finding emails

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

How do I convert this search regex into a regex I can use in a find and replace operation in either Sublime Text or SED or Vim?

**EDIT:**

Just a note, I just realized I could replace all strings found by `@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b` in this case, but academically I am still interested in how you could treat each section of the email regex as a token and replace the username / domain independently.

Comment: There is no difference between a search and a find-and-replace regex, is there? If you want to do the job properly you might want to have a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) though.

Comment: @m.buettner, isn't there though, don't I need to separate out the email address into tokens and replace a specific token so I am not replacing the entire email address?

Comment: You can search for only the domain (`@....`) and replace it - if you can make the assumption that `@` doesn't appear in other context. You can also use capturing group and backreference.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon oh I see what you mean. my bad.

Comment: fake.com is an owned domain name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SublimeText**

[SublimeText](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html) uses [Boost syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), which supports quite a large subset of features in Perl regex. But for this task, you don't need all those advanced constructs.

Below are 2 possible approaches:

1. If you can assume that `@` doesn't appear in any other context (which is quite a fair assumption for normal text), then you can just search for the domain part `@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b` and replace it.
2. If you use capturing groups `(pattern)` and backreference in replacement string.

   **Find what**

   ```
   \b([A-Z0-9._%-]+)@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
   ```

   `([A-Z0-9._%-]+)` is the first (and only) capturing group in the regex.

   **Replace with**

   ```
   $1@fake.com
   ```

   `$1` refers to the text captured by the first capturing group.

Note that for both methods above, you need to turn off case-sensitivity (indicated as the 2nd button on the lower left corner), unless you specifically want to remove only emails written in ALL CAPS.

Comment: An alternative way of doing it would be to use *positive lookbehind* to avoid capturing the first half of the email and only target the domain.

Comment: @plalx: Look-behind may not always work, since the pattern is variable-width.

Comment: good to know, I had implemented the same solution as you but was fooling around with lookbehind and could not made it work. I guess that explains why... I"ll read more about it ;)

Comment: fake.com is actually an owned domain name. Don't use that.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following command for Vim:

```
:%s/\(\<[A-Za-z0-9._%-]\+@\)[A-Za-z0-9.-]\+\.[A-Za-z]\{2,4}\>/\1fake.com/g
```

Everything between `\(` and `\)` will become a group that will be replaced by an escaped number of the group (`\1` in this case). I've also modified the regexp to match the small letters and to have Vim-compatible syntax.

Also you may turn off the case sensitivity by putting `\c` anywhere in your regexp like this:

```
:%s/\c\(\<[A-Z0-9._%-]\+@\)[A-Z0-9.-]\+\.[A-Z]\{2,4}\>/\1fake.com/g
```

Please also note that `%` in the beginning of the line asks Vim to do the replacement in a whole file and `g` at the end to do multiple replacements in the same line.

One more approach is using the zero-width matching (`\@<=`):

```
:%s/\c\(\<[A-Z0-9._%-]\+@\)\@<=[A-Z0-9.-]\+\.[A-Z]\{2,4}\>/fake.com/g
```

Comment: Does vim support `i` flag? If it does, then you don't have to modify the regex to support case-sensitivity.

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks for your suggestion. I've added a version with `\c` flag :)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is just as good as nhahtdh's, but I ended up using sublime for the change so I gave him the answer

Comment: @JamesMcMahon You're welcome. And no problem. I like his answer as well :)

Comment: I've had a terrible time trying to translate your regex into sed syntax, any advice?