# Regex Expression to replace email address domain, for users email address

Tags: regex, email, office365

I am trying to solve an email domain co-existence problem with Exchange online. Basically i need it so when a message is sent to one tenant (domain.com) and forwarded to another tenant (newdomain.com) - that the To and/or CC headers are replaced with the endpoint (newdomain.com) email addresses before they are delivered to the final destination.

**For Example:**

1) Gmail (or any) user sends and email to sally.sue@domain.com, MX is looked up for that domain, it is delivered to the Office 365 Tenant for domain.com

2) That same office 365 tenant, is set to forward emails to sally.sue@newdomain.com (different tenant)

3) When the message arrives to sally sue at newdomain.com and she hits "Reply All" the original sender AND her (sally.sue@domain.com) are added to the To: line in the email.

The way to fix that is to use Header Replacement with Proofpoint, which as mentioned below works on a single users basis. The entire question below is me trying to get it to work using RegEx (As thats the only solution) for a large number of users.

**I need to convert the following users email address:**

username@domain.com to username@newdomain.com

This has to be done using ProofPoint which is a cloud hosted MTA. They have been able to provide some sort of an answer but its not working.

**Proofpoint support has suggested using this:**

```
Header Name : To
Find Value  : domain\.com$
Replace     : newdomain\.com$ or just newdomain.com
```

Neither of the above work. In both cases the values are just completely ignored.

**This seems to find the values:**

```
Header Name : To
Find Value  : \b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
Replace     : $1@fake.com
```

But the above simply and only replaces the To: line (in the email) with the literal string: $1@fake.com

I would also need to be able to find lowercase and numbers in email addresses as well. i believe the above example only finds caps.

**I need it do the following:**

```
Header Name : To
Find Value  : \b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b (find users email address, domain) 
Replace     : user.name@newdomain.com
```

This is for a large number of users so there is no way to manually update or create separate rules for each user.

If i do create a individual rule, then it works as expected but as stated that requires manually typing out each user To: address And their new desired To: address.

This solution here almost worked: [Regex to replace email address domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071421/regex-to-replace-email-address-domains)

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of observations from general experience, although I have not worked with Office365 specifically.

First, a regex used for replacement usually needs to have a "capture group".  This is often expressed with parentheses, as in:

```
match       : \b([A-Z0-9._%-]+)@domain.com$
replacement : $1@newdomain.com
```

The idea is that the `$1` in the replacement pattern is replaced with whatever was found within the `()` in the matching pattern.

Note that some regex engines use a different symbol for the replacement, so it might be `\1@newdomain.com` or some such.  Note also that some regex engines need the parentheses escaped, so the matching pattern might be something like `\b\([A-Z0-9._%-]+\)@domain.com$`

Second, if you want to include `-` inside a "character class" set (that is, inside square brackets `[]`), then the `-` should be first; otherwise it's ambiguous because `-` is also used for a range of characters.  The regex engine in question might not care, but I suggest writing your matching pattern as:

```
\b([-A-Z0-9._%]+)@domain.com$
```

This way, the first `-` is unambiguously itself, because there is nothing before it to indicate the start of a range.

Third, for lowercase letters, it's easiest to just expand your character class set to include them, like so:

```
[-A-Za-z0-9._%]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have just tried your suggestions, however no change. If I leave this as is:

Header Name : To
Find Value  : \b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
Replace     : $1@fake.com

Then it will replace as you can see above with \b@fake.com - literal replacement. 

It seems that any other capture variable does not work, and all that occurs is the email is ignored.

Would there be any type of documentation I could request from the Vendor? This is all based on send mail. 

Thanks, 

Robert

Comment: @RobertB : since you are asking about Exchange and Office365, then yes, I assume that Microsoft has documentation, as well as a variety of other technical support options; I don't deal with Microsoft as a vendor at all myself, but I'm sure they can help

Comment: landru. 

In this case Exchange/Office365 do not apply here as I am trying to get ProofPoint to implement regex. 

In our case it goes like this:

EMail Sent to Domain >> MX (delivers to) ProofPoint >> (PP implements regex) >> then office 365.

I would have the same request, even if ProofPoint was delivering to say gmail.com (g-suite).

Comment: @RobertB : I apologize; I misunderstood; my experience with ProofPoint itself is even less than with Microsoft; but I googled "proofpoint using regular expression to alter recipient email address" and the 2nd hit is for the Proofpoint Essentials Administrator Guide; that sounds like it might help, and on page 5 of that document is mention of both a KnowledgeBase and a tech support line; one of those should be able to answer your question

Comment: Ok thanks. I will check there. I scanned through the Manual before but just didn't get anywhere in terms of a solution.

Comment: From ProofPoint Support: 

We are unable to change the envelope recipient within the email firewall rules. This is something that can only be done on a per domain basis within the mailer tables. The email firewall rules are only able to change the header to and from values. Since the <newdomain.com> tenant is unable to accept messages for those <domain.com> addresses that are being redirected, we will not be able to perform the redirect within Proofpoint in this way.

Comment: The sad part is, I have the first part of it working, the last part is however where I am stuck. 

I am able to get it to change any email address, yet what it replaces it with is just the literal value of: $1\domain.com. damn.